# How to prove that the square root of the determinant of a matrix is $\sqrt{1+|\nabla \varphi|^2}$, the differential of area

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to compute the area of the graph of a scalar function $\varphi : \mathbb{R}^n \longmapsto \mathbb{R}$ over a domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

In dimension 2, if the surface is parametrized by
\begin{align}
    \sigma : \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2 & \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3} \\ x & \longmapsto (x, \varphi(x)),
\end{align}
then the area of the graph of $\varphi$ is
\begin{equation*}
    \int_{\Omega} |\sigma_u \times \sigma_v| \text{ }dx.
\end{equation*}

When one goes to dimension $n$, the vector product can not be used anymore. Then, since $|\sigma_u \times \sigma_v|$ gives the area of the parallelepiped spanned by the two vectors $\sigma_u, \sigma_v \in \mathbb{R}^3$, we want to compute this quantity (the area/volume/hypervolume) for $n$ vectors of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Such vectors are the columns of $D_{\sigma}$, and the quantity that we want is (using Gram's matrix)
\begin{equation*}
    \sqrt{\det D_{\sigma}^T D_{\sigma}}.
\end{equation*}

What I need to see is that $\sqrt{\det D_{\sigma}^T D_{\sigma}} = \sqrt{1+ |\nabla \varphi |^2}$.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4749895/568204) answer of mine, especially the middle where I give the ‘curious determinant formula’ and at the end when applying to graphs of functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer solved my problem perfectly. Multilinearity of the determinant was the key! @peek-a-boo